# How should I put ContractTransactionResponse object into a contact function return value I need in hardhat when I test My code

Tags: testing, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

I found that only when I set the function to view the test script to get to contract function returns the value of the contract, otherwise it will return a ContractTransactionResponse object, if need to modify a contract function chain data and return data to the script How should I put ContractTransactionResponse object into a contact function return value I need in hardhat when I test My code

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6S4z.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pnss.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISmE4.png)